# what does the average lemmatization length tell us about a body of text?

Tags: computational-linguistics

In computational linguistics or in NLP, what does the value of average lemmatized length tells us about a document?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The average length of lemmata in a corpus does not tell much definitively in itself.

It is not clear to me if you are asking about absolute length or length relative to unlemmatised surface form.

If two corpora of similar size and structure differ in average absolute lemma length or average word length for that matter, it could be that they are in different languages, or that they are using very different registers of the same language.

If two corpora differ in the average difference between lemma length and word length, then it could be that one is in a higher-morphology language or compounding language.

But these are just correlations, without more context it is tea-leaf reading, and there are more straightforward ways to determine those features.

Comment: to narrow down the scope, I want to use this value to compute an index for the given document (in a collection). This index could be level of innovation (requiring other values/features analogous to average lemmatized length). Getting a sense of morphology of the language can be useful perhaps to classify if a doc is in German vs English or Spanish.